# word 2010 footer change text from second page

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

I search and change the text in the footer like this:

```
Sub 123()
    Dim xDoc As Document
    Dim xSelection As Selection
    Dim xSec As Section
    Dim xHeader As HeaderFooter
  Dim xFooter As HeaderFooter
On Error Resume Next
    Set xDoc = Application.ActiveDocument
    For Each xSec In xDoc.Sections
          For Each xFooter In xSec.Footers
            xFooter.Range.Select
            Set xSelection = xDoc.Application.Selection
            With xSelection.Find
                .Text = "text1"
                .Replacement.Text = "text2"
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With
        Next xFooter
    Next xSec
    xDoc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Close
    If xDoc.ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial = wdPaneNone Then
        xDoc.ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdPrintView
    Else
        xDoc.ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdPrintView
    End If
    xDoc.Activate
End Sub
```

After the macro works, several empty lines are added to the first page. How can I make the macro work from the second page of the document?

UPDATE:
I described the problem incorrectly, it does not create rows, it adds an empty header.

UPDATE 2:

I solved the problem with the help of the code:

```
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageFooter
```

Comment: Firstly, when working with a document in VBA it is rarely necessary to select anything, and it certainly isn't necessary for this. Secondly, every range of a Word document, including headers and footers, contains at least one paragraph.

Comment: What you will need to be changing will be either the primary footer or the even-page footer. Every section in Word can contain three footers. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#Recap_of_Header/Footer_settings

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
Sub abc()
    Dim xDoc As Document
    Dim xSec As Section
    Dim xHeader As HeaderFooter
    Dim xFooter As HeaderFooter
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xDoc = Application.ActiveDocument
    For Each xSec In xDoc.Sections
        For Each xFooter In xSec.Footers
            If xFooter.Exists Then
                With xFooter.Range.Find
                    .Text = "text1"
                    .Replacement.Text = "text2"
                    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
                End With
            End If
        Next xFooter
    Next xSec
End Sub
```

Comment: the code performs its task, but the problem with the first page remains